# How to set If-Modified-Since header in AWS S3 using Go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I have a function to download a file from S3. It works but does not recognize the IfModifiedSince option. The below function looks for the same named file locally, and if present sets a time.Time object to the Modification date and time. That is then used in the request to S3 to only download the file if it has been modified since then.

```
func DownloadS3Media(filename string, mediaDirectory string, bucket string, c *configuration.Configuration) (dest string, bytes int64, err error) {
    os.Setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", c.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
    os.Setenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", c.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

    // Create the directories in the path
    finalFilePath := filepath.Join(mediaDirectory, filename)
    if err1 := os.MkdirAll(filepath.Dir(finalFilePath), 0775); err1 != nil {
        return "", 0, err1
    }

    //Create the blank file to push the data into
    var t *time.Time
    if fi, err2 := os.Stat(finalFilePath); err2 == nil {
        t1 := fi.ModTime()
        t = &t1
    }
    tempFilePath := filepath.Join(mediaDirectory, filename + ".tmp")
    tempFile, err3 := os.Create(tempFilePath)
    if err3 != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to create file", err3)
        return finalFilePath, 0, err3
    }
    defer tempFile.Close()

    logLevel := aws.LogDebug
    downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(session.New(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-east-1"), LogLevel:&logLevel}))
    params := &s3.GetObjectInput{Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(filename),
        IfModifiedSince: t}
    numBytes, err4 := downloader.Download(tempFile, params)
    if err4 != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to download file", err4)
        return finalFilePath, 0, err4
    }

    //if downloader pulled down the file, rename the tmp file to original.
    if _, err5 := os.Stat(tempFilePath); err5 == nil {
        os.Rename(tempFilePath, finalFilePath)
        log.Println("Renamed ", tempFilePath, "to", finalFilePath)
    }

    log.Println("Downloaded file", filename, "to", finalFilePath, numBytes, "bytes")
    return finalFilePath, numBytes, nil
}
```

When debugging, I see the proper value for &t which is ﻿something like `sec: 63606119179`. By the time AWS sends the request, the header is present but is set to 1/1/0001.

```
---[ REQUEST POST-SIGN ]-----------------------------
GET http://*****.s3.amazonaws.com/domenic-test.png HTTP/1.1
Host: *****.s3.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: aws-sdk-go/1.3.1 (go1.6.3; darwin; amd64) S3Manager
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential= *****/20160806/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;if-modified-since;range;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature= *****
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 1 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT
Range: bytes=0-5242879
X-Amz-Content-Sha256: *****
X-Amz-Date: 20160806T223302Z
```

Comment: This ended up being a defect in the Amazon code which has since been corrected and released.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simplification:

```
var t time.Time
if fi, err2 := os.Stat(finalFilePath); err2 == nil {
    t := fi.ModTime()
}
```

and later:

```
params := &s3.GetObjectInput{Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    Key:    aws.String(filename),
    IfModifiedSince: aws.Time(t)}
```

...as suggested in the example code here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/f1e26250235022af782521266389e4b2ae2945e4/service/s3/examples_test.go#L975

At first I thought it was an erasure issue, but after testing, I find that the `time.Time` value that `t` was pointing to escapes the block (which honestly surprised me). Maybe there's some other bug happening in between the two, but I would assume that since their tests are passing, this should work.

Comment: I tried that modification, but still seeing:
`If-Modified-Since: Mon, 1 Jan 0001 00:00:00 GMT`

Comment: FWIW, their tests don't address the IfModifiedSince header. I do have an open ticket with AWS.

Comment: Sorry... tried my best. Good luck with that ticket! Let me know how it goes.